# Regexp flag DOTALL in sed or alternatives

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to replace part of a file that matches a regexp. The point is, that it has to work over whole file as a single string like `grep -Pzo`, but, as far as I know, `sed` is line-based.

I have tried to force `sed` to do this by manipulating `IFS`, but I am still inexperienced in `bash` and I am not really sure about what I'm doing.
I hope you will help me clarify some things that I don't understand.

So I made something like this:

```
 OIFS=$IFS
 IFS=""
 content=$(cat -v file  | sed 's/(?<=<\/div>(?!.*\/div>)).*//') 
 #Remove everything begining from last </div> to the end of file.
 IFS=$OIFS
```

But I doesn't work as I intended. I was also experimenting with `perl` to make this substitution, but the problem seems to be the same.
I will appreciate any tips.

EDIT:
According to comments below I am pasting some example data:

```
 Source:
    <html>
    <body>
    <div>
        some site with many <div> divs </div>
           <div> and more <div> even more </div> </div>
    </div> <!-- last div closing -->
    This is all to be deleted
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then after: `s/</div>(?<=<\/div>(?!.*\/div>)).*//s`

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    some site with many <div> divs </div>
       <div> and more <div> even more </div> </div>
```

EDIT 2:
I found yet simpler way than suggested below:

```
cat file | perl -0pe 's/(?<=<\/div>(?!.*\/div>)).*//'
```

-0 causes record separator to be null, which makes perl to process whole string in one run instead of looping through lines.

Comment: What is your sample input and expected output?

Comment: May be you should be using `xmlstarlet` because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1422630)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more general solution:

```
$ cat file | tr '\n' '\r' | sed 's,\(.*</div>\).*,\1,' | tr '\r' '\n'
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      some site with many <div> divs </div>
      <div> and more <div> even more </div> </div>
    </div>
```

Explanation:

`tr '\n' '\r'` replaces newlines by carriage returns so `sed` will treat the file content as one line.

`sed 's,\(.*</div>\).*,\1,'` removes everything beyond the last match of `</div>`.

`tr '\r' '\n'` replaces the remaining carriage returns by newlines.

Note: if your original file contains windows-style \r\n newlines, first convert to unix style newlines:

```
$ cat file | dos2unix | tr '\n' '\r' | sed 's,\(.*</div>\).*,\1,' | tr '\r' '\n' | unix2dos
```

Comment: and if we want to match a "whole line" just instead of ^$ enclose with `\r`, seems a good trick, thx! :D, we just need to make it sure there wasnt any \r before beggining, but probably would be a windows text file, so just remove them all b4 beggining and re-add after if thats the case.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by reversing your input file, deleting everything until the first `</div>` and then reversing again:

```bash
tac input.txt | sed '1,/<\/div>/d' | tac > output.txt
```

This will remove the last line which contains a `</div>`and everything after it.

Alternative with `sed` (although not pretty, and I'm sure there is a cleverer way to do it):

```
tr '\n' '~' < input.txt | sed -r 's~(.*)</div>.*~\1~g' | tr '~' '\n' > output.txt
```

Replace newlines with a placeholder (`~` in this example) so everything is on one line, match that line up until the last `</div>`, then replace the newlines again. Choose a placeholder according to your input data, obviously it should be something which does not occur.

Comment: That should do. I have tried a simmilar approach, but I was using `rev`, which caused the same problem that I had with `sed`. I didn't know that the `tac` exists. Thanks.

Comment: I am still curious if I can make my previous code working. This time the `tac` is fine, but it is easy to imagine that this will not be sufficient.

Comment: Added an additional way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Some like this `awk`

```
awk '/<\/div>/ {exit} 1' file
```

This will `exit` when pattern found.

Comment: This is not exactly what I intended. The goal is to remove everything begining from the LAST </div> in file. But thanks.

Comment: @Liberat0r That is why people ask you to post example data.  Updated my answer.

Comment: I assumed, that if someone is not able to understand given regexp, will not be able to help me anyway :P.

Comment: @Liberat0r If you look, you see anubhava, a senior here in the forum is asking for that. And two other upvoted his reply.  So it might not always be easy to understand what is asked.